# How to change all paragraph text colors and size dynamically onclick within a <div>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, paragraph

*The following fiddle allows text to be pasted into a `<textarea>` and generated into paragraphs on button click.*

Is it possible, within the following code below, to create two dropdown lists `<select></select>`, one that changes the color of the paragraphs `<p>` to any color the user selects on click and the other to change the size of the text dynamically?

Attached is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zdCyq/15/). It would be extremely helpful if the fiddle could please be updated, as I am still new to coding.

HTML:

```
<div>
<div id="text_land" style="border:1px solid #ccc; padding:25px; margin-bottom:30px;">xzxz</div>
<textarea style="width:95%;"></textarea>
<button>Go</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
  $('button').on('click', function () {
    var theText = $('textarea').val();
    var i = 200;
    while (theText.length > 200) {
        console.log('looping');
        while (theText.charAt(i) !== '.') {
            i++;   
        }

        console.log(i);
        $("#text_land").append("<p>" + theText.substring(0, i+1) + "</p>");
        theText = theText.substring(i+1);
        i = 200;
    }

    $('#text_land').append("<p>" + theText + "</p>");
  })

})
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you've already accepted an answer, I thought I'd offer a slight alternative; which is a little more concise and, hopefully, obvious as to how to extend further to support other css properties:

```js
$(function() {
  
  // a slight change to your own approach,
  // binding an anonymous function as the
  // click event-handler of the <button>:
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    
    // getting the value of the <textarea>
    // element that follows the '#text_land'
    // element:
    var v = $('#text_land + textarea').val(),
        
        // splitting the value on double-
        // linebreaks to allow paragraphs to
        // be formed, and joining the array-
        // elements together with closing and
        // opening tags; then wrapping the
        // whole string in an opening and
        // closing tag:
      paragraphs = '<p>' + v.split(/\n\n/).join('</p><p>') + '</p>';
    
    // appending the paragraphs to the
    // '#text_land' element:
    $(paragraphs).appendTo('#text_land');
  });

  // binding an anonymous function as the
  // change event-handler for the <select>
  // elements:
  $('select').on('change', function() {
    
    // finding the elements that should
    // be affected:
    var targets = $('#text_land p'),
        
        // finding the CSS property to
        // update (held in the
        // 'data-property' attribute):
      property = this.dataset.property;

    // updating the CSS property of
    // those elements with the
    // property-value held in the 
    // <select> element's value property:
    targets.css(property, this.value);
    
    // because we're using disabled <option>
    // elements to act as the 'label' within
    // the <select> we set the selectedIndex
    // property to 0 (since those disabled
    // <label> elements are the first <option>
    // which shows the 'label' on page-load,
    // but the disabled attribute/property
    // prevents the user from re-selecting it):
  }).prop('selectedIndex', 0);
});
```

```css
#text_land {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
textarea {
  width: 95%;
}
label {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
}
label select {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="styles">
    <!--
    wrapping the <select> elements in <label> elements, so that
    clicking the text will focus the <select>:
    -->
    <label>Color:
      <!--
      using a custom data-* attribute to store the css property
      that each <select> will affect/update:
      -->
      <select data-property="color">
        <!--
        Setting the first <option> to 'disabled' in order that
        the user cannot select the (pseudo) 'label' text:
        -->
        <option disabled>Select color:</option>
        <option>red</option>
        <option>green</option>
        <option>blue</option>
      </select>
    </label>
    <label>Font-size:
      <select data-property="font-size">
        <option disabled>Select font-size:</option>
        <option>smaller</option>
        <option>10px</option>
        <option>12px</option>
        <option>14px</option>
        <option>16px</option>
        <option>18px</option>
        <option>20px</option>
        <option>larger</option>
      </select>
    </label>
    <label>Background-color:
      <select data-property="background-color">
        <option disabled>Select background-color:</option>
        <option>aqua</option>
        <option>fuchsia</option>
        <option>limegreen</option>
        <option>silver</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div id="text_land">xzxz</div>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <button>Go</button>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/by8rcsrm/).

The advantage of this approach is that one event-handler can act as the event handler for all the `<select>` elements, so long as the appropriate values are given in the `<option>` tags, and the appropriate CSS property is held in the `data-property` attribute of the `<select>` element itself. This avoids the need to write out event-handlers for each individual `<select>` element that updates a different property-value.

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
  - [Guide to JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
  - [`Element.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).
  - [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
- jQuery:

  - [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
  - [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).
  - [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: Thank you for the updated code! While both code suggestions, including the answer below are great, I will select this answer as the solution, due to being able to support other css properties.

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have helped; and thank you for the acceptance! :)

Comment: Also, is it possible, with this new code, to specify how many characters are in each paragraph, like the original fiddle? Thank you.

Comment: Oh, absolutely; I changed that purely for brevity. You could easily replace the paragraph-insertion from my code with your own original.

Answer (score 3):

Following is the [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/zdCyq/60/).

#### Code

```js
$(function () {
    $('button').on('click', function () {
        var theText = $('textarea').val();
        var i = 200;
        while (theText.length > 200) {
            console.log('looping');
            while (theText.charAt(i) !== '.') {
                i++;   
            }
            
            console.log(i);
            $("#text_land").append("<p>" + theText.substring(0, i+1) + "</p>");
            theText = theText.substring(i+1);
            i = 200;
        }
        
        $('#text_land').append("<p>" + theText + "</p>");
    })
    
    $("#color").on("change", function(){
     $("#text_land").css("color", $(this).val())
    });
    
    $("#size").on("change", function(){
     $("#text_land").css("font-size", $(this).val());
    });
    
    $("#bgcolor").on("change", function(){
     $("#text_land").css("background", $(this).val())
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div id="text_land" style="border:1px solid #ccc; padding:25px; margin-bottom:30px;">xzxz</div>
    <textarea style="widht:95%;"></textarea>
    <button>Go</button>
</div>

<select id="color">
    <option>Color</option>
    <option>Red</option>
    <option>Blue</option>
    <option>Black</option>
    <option>Green</option>
</select>

<select id="bgcolor">
    <option>Background Color</option>
    <option>Red</option>
    <option>Blue</option>
    <option>Black</option>
    <option>Green</option>
</select>


<select id="size">
    <option>Size</option>
    <option>16px</option>
    <option>18px</option>
    <option>20px</option>
    <option>22px</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the updated code! Is it possible to have another dropdown list which changes the background color of each paragraph section and not the spaces between the paragraphs <p>?

Comment: Just put text in `<p>` tag instead of `<div>` and it will work. Also update ID to match one in JS.

Answer (score 0):

1. create css classes eg: .red,.blue etc

   .red {
     color : red;
   }
2. On change of dropdown value, loop through the `<p>` tags in the block and add the required class to the `<p>` tags (`<p class="red">`).

Repeat the same for changing the font size by creating css class of required font size